# How to specify a unique React$Element as the flow type

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I am trying to specify that a function should only return a specific type of React$Element. Looking at the source code the following should work, but it doesn't:

```
/* @flow */

import React, { Component } from 'react';

type Props = {
  testID: string
}

class Price extends Component {
    props: Props;

    render() {
        return null
    }
}

function bla() : React$Element<Price> {
  return <Price testID="fds"/>;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
18:   return <Price testID="fds"/>;
             ^ props of React element `Price`. This type is incompatible with
17: function bla() : React$Element<Price> {
                                   ^ Price
18:   return <Price testID="fds"/>;
             ^ property `testID`. Property not found in
17: function bla() : React$Element<Price> {
                                   ^ Price
```

Here is a playground link of the error happening:

https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBcwAlAUwEMBjQgGjAG8wBhOXOAOzI+IF8wo+NmADk+SjREBudIQCeOMmAAKQnAGcwAXkaowYQmXWEAkgBEAXGGP4MHAOape6KjArrNqjFSVkAHoYcACaarOxcPLr6+jhq6laqcBoyqACQ4sFk+AAUAJRR0elkhACu+BxgHCUwMHrRzs6oUCUcNBicYABGbnlgVuTUhAAkAKIwZFjchAA8Xj4AfAXipeVgs7Y+BkamZloARFAhe8DzMrxAA

(you might have to switch the flow version to v0.43 from v0.43.1)

edit: As Nate suggested below I can pass the Props as the type parameter but then, flow wouldn't complain if the function is returning another React Element with the same Props type.

Comment: any reason for the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but my guess is that in the original version of the question, you just said that it "didn't work" and didn't provide any additional information. You've since edited to include adequate information.

Comment: Also, I don't know how to solve your actual problem but `React$Elements`'s type parameter is for the props, not the actual element type. If you change the return type from `React$Element<Price>` to `React$Element<Props>` the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Flow 0.53.0 included major improvements for React. One of those changes was a [`React.Element<typeof Component>` type](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-element).

To use this new type, you'll either have to import React with `import * as React from 'react'`, which will import the React types as well as the React library, so you can use `React.Element`. Or you can explicitly import the type(s) you need, for example `import React, { Component, type Element as ReactElement } from 'react'`, and use `ReactElement`.

Using your example code, it would look something like this:

```
/* @flow */
import React, { Component, type Element as ReactElement } from 'react';

type Props = {
    testID: string
}

class Price extends Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return null
    }
}

function bla() : ReactElement<typeof Price> {
    return <Price testID="fds"/>;
}
```

Or, [here it is in Flow's playground](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuYASgKYCGAxgQDRgDeYAwnDnAHanu1gECe2UmACiMUpi5FyAZxIVqo8ZLABfMFDyswAcjzyC2gNypU-QWAAKm7LIC8DVAEgCpaQQCSAEQBcYN3nR2AHNUFRNKGBlZK3RKIVIADxd2ABNZFjZObgAeKzgbAD4HRz1U0jwACgBKBzA6sBLSAgBXPHYwdmaYGFR61VCTKGb2anQOMAAjSOqwXzIqAkUJHLNSOChLALii+ic9FrawXK2hFzcvWwAiKDTL4ALjMKA).

Answer (score -1):

1) There are a bunch of 404 is you use the default version 0.43.1. You need to contact `flow` to correct the issue

[image]

2) Switching to prev version reveals the following issues:

[image]

Comment: Sure thank you for the screenshot i was already using 0.43, should have added the errors i was seeing in the question. But yea with those errors i still dont understand how i should specify the return type